# Underlaying Connection Issue while using TransactionScope

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions

I am facing following error when opening multiple SqlConnection in my Application. I had configured the DTC, Firewall. But the same code is working fine in Miscosoft Enterprise Library. When i am manually trying to open the connection facing following error.

**"The MSDTC transaction manager was unable to pull the transaction from the source transaction manager due to communication problems. Possible causes are: a firewall is present and it doesn't have an exception for the MSDTC process, the two machines cannot find each other by their NetBIOS names, or the support for network transactions is not enabled for one of the two transaction managers. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D02B)"**

Comment: Do you really need [MSDTC](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/sql-server/what-exactly-is-msdtc-any-when-do-i-need-it/)?

Comment: Check if the connectionstring is using the netbios name of the server, instead of IP or DNS name